# CloudKit Console "Internal Error" after Querying Records

Tags: cloudkit

My app was running fine with no problems using CloudKit. Suddenly, today, views that previously displayed the requested data are not doing so, and when I visit the CloudKit console to run a query there, I receive "Internal Error" (see screenshot for reference) and no other explanation. Has this happened to others? Is there a better way to figure out what's wrong?
[image: screenshot of cloudkit console]
Needless to say, this is very concerning as an important feature of my app is not working. Any help / direction will be immensely appreciated!